# Pass specific value from feeder to script in gatling

Tags: scala, gatling, scala-gatling

I am working on performance test, for that I have below Gatling script -

```
val getUserById: ChainBuilder = feed(userEmailFeeder).exec(http("User By Id")
  .get("url")
  .headers(getHeaders)
  .check(status is 200)
)

private val getHeaders = Map.apply(
  "Content-Type" -> "application/json",
  "Accept" -> "application/json",
  "token" -> {tokenValue}
)

object BearerToken {
  //Generating token here
}
```

In `userEmailFeeder` I have user emails and passwords. I have to generate a token for every email present in feeder and add to header in `getHeader`.

Can someone guide me how I can pass same `email` & associated `password` to `BearerToken` for which `getUserById` is referring from feeder so it will genearte token and add into `header`?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a method to get your email and password from a session, generate a token, and then write these values to a session.

```
val generateTokenByEmailAndPassword: Expression[Session] = (session: Session) => {
    val email = session("email").as[String]
    val password = session("password").as[String]

    // your logic for generate token
    val token = email + password

    session.set("tokenValue", token)
  }
```

And then add to scenario:

```
...

.feed(userEmailFeeder)
.exec(generateTokenByEmailAndPassword)
.exec(http("User By Id")

...
```

---

A little remark - for get session value need to add $

Wrong: `{tokenValue}`

Right way: `#{tokenValue}`